Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to activate 'Project.Common.Providers.CategoryStandardValuesProvider'
I'm working on the upgrade 8.2 to 10.4. all the updates done and after the deployment faced the below issue.
Server Error in '/' Application.
Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to activate 'Project.Common.Providers.CategoryStandardValuesProvider'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to activate 'Project.Common.Providers.CategoryStandardValuesProvider'.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to activate 'Project.Common.Providers.CategoryStandardValuesProvider'.]
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider) +410
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters) +365
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromServiceProvider(XmlNode configNode, Boolean assert) +481

[ConfigurationException: Could not create object from service provider . Config XML: <add name="CategoryStandardValuesProvider" type="Project.Common.Providers.CategoryStandardValuesProvider, Project.Common" resolve="true" patch:source="CategoryStandardValuesProvider.config" xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/"><param name="commerceConnectProductClassificationFieldID">{C14B0AAA-0936-4B73-BD07-8B540C0B4B14}</param><FieldMappings hint="list:AddFieldMappings"><StandardValueFieldMapping type="Project.StandardValueFieldMapping, Project.Models"><SourceFieldID>{1D747EFC-EBD6-43FB-BA0F-9A252FC05E43}</SourceFieldID><TargetStandardValueFieldName>name</TargetStandardValueFieldName></StandardValueFieldMapping><StandardValueFieldMapping type="Project.StandardValueFieldMapping, Project.Models"><SourceFieldID>{77741F9A-523B-4CE8-886B-A6F4EB6C37DF}</SourceFieldID><TargetStandardValueFieldName>description</TargetStandardValueFieldName></StandardValueFieldMapping></FieldMappings></add>]
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromServiceProvider(XmlNode configNode, Boolean assert) +641
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +138
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, Boolean assert) +68
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetProviders(List`1 nodes) +311
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetProviders(String rootPath, TProvider& defaultProvider) +323
   Sitecore.Configuration.ProviderHelper`2.ReadProviders() +75
   Sitecore.Configuration.ProviderHelper`2.get_Provider() +116
   Sitecore.Data.DefaultStandardValuesManager..ctor(ProviderHelper`2 providerHelper) +18
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context) +407
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) +274
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context) +158
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) +377
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope) +63
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType) +279
   System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory) +75
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope) +46
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType) +103
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider) +51
   Sitecore.DependencyInjection.LazyResetable`1.get_Value() +150
   Sitecore.Data.Fields.Field.GetStandardValue() +21
   Sitecore.Pipelines.GetFieldValue.GetStandardValue.Process(GetFieldValueArgs args) +34
   (Object , Object ) +9
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +294
   Sitecore.Data.Fields.Field.GetValue(Boolean allowStandardValue, Boolean allowDefaultValue, Boolean allowFallbackValue, Boolean allowInheritValue, Boolean allowInnerValue) +333
   Sitecore.Data.Fields.Field.GetValue(Boolean allowStandardValue, Boolean allowDefaultValue, Boolean allowFallbackValue, Boolean allowInheritValue) +44
   Sitecore.Data.Fields.Field.GetValue(Boolean allowStandardValue, Boolean allowDefaultValue, Boolean allowFallbackValue) +29
   Sitecore.Data.Fields.Field.get_Value() +25
   Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.ItemAuthorizationHelper.GetAccessRules(Item item) +59
   Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.DefaultAuthorizationManager.GetAccessRules(ISecurable entity) +18
   Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.ItemSecurity.GetAccessRules() +48
   Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.ItemAuthorizationHelper.GetItemAccess(Item item, Account account, AccessRight accessRight, PropagationType propagationType) +313
   Sitecore.Buckets.Security.AuthenticationHelper.GetItemAccess(Item item, Account account, AccessRight accessRight, PropagationType propagationType) +50
   Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.ItemAuthorizationHelper.GetAccess(Item item, Account account, AccessRight accessRight) +331
   Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.AuthorizationProvider.GetAccess(ISecurable entity, Account account, AccessRight accessRight) +195
   Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.DefaultAuthorizationManager.GetAccess(ISecurable entity, Account account, AccessRight accessRight) +106
   Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.DefaultAuthorizationManager.IsAllowed(ISecurable entity, AccessRight right, Account account) +105
   Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.ItemAccess.CanRead() +63
   Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemProvider.ApplySecurity(Item item, SecurityCheck securityCheck) +81
   Sitecore.Data.Managers.DefaultItemManager.GetItem(ID itemId, Language language, Version version, Database database) +147
   Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemManager.GetItem(ID itemId, Language language, Version version, Database database) +154
   Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.Outcomes.Data.ItemDb.ItemOutcomeDefinitionRepository..ctor(ILogger`1 logger, String databaseName, Boolean assumeActive, IDefinitionRecordMapper`1 mapper) +874
   Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.Outcomes.Data.ItemDb.ItemOutcomeDefinitionRepository..ctor(ILogger`1 logger, IItemRepositoriesSettings settings, IDefinitionRecordMapper`1 mapper) +234
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context) +407
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) +274
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context) +158
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) +377
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope) +63
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType) +279
   System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory) +75
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope) +46
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType) +103
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider) +51
   Sitecore.Marketing.xMgmt.Pipelines.Initialize.InitializeOutcomeDefinitionRepositoryProcessor..ctor() +31
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider) +560
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters) +365
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromServiceProvider(XmlNode configNode, Boolean assert) +481

[ConfigurationException: Could not create object from service provider . Config XML: <processor type="Sitecore.Marketing.xMgmt.Pipelines.Initialize.InitializeOutcomeDefinitionRepositoryProcessor, Sitecore.Marketing.xMgmt" resolve="true" patch:source="Sitecore.Marketing.config" xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" />]
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromServiceProvider(XmlNode configNode, Boolean assert) +641
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +138
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, Boolean assert) +68
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipelineFactory.GetObjectFromType(XmlNode processorNode) +91
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipelineFactory.GetProcessorObject(XmlNode processorNode) +138
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CoreProcessor.GetMethod(Object[] parameters) +136
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +1437
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +236
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Application_Start() +146
   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Init(HttpApplication app) +918
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +584
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +168
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +277
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +369

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not create object from service provider . Config XML: <processor type="Sitecore.Marketing.xMgmt.Pipelines.Initialize.InitializeOutcomeDefinitionRepositoryProcessor, Sitecore.Marketing.xMgmt" resolve="true" patch:source="Sitecore.Marketing.config" xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" />]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +532
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +111
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +719

and the patch config file.
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <standardValues>
      <providers>
        <add name="CategoryStandardValuesProvider" type="Project.Common.Providers.CategoryStandardValuesProvider, Project.Common" resolve="true">
          <param name="commerceConnectProductClassificationFieldID">{C14B0AAA-0936-4B73-BD07-8B540C0B4B14}</param>
          <FieldMappings hint="list:AddFieldMappings">
            <StandardValueFieldMapping type="Project.StandardValueFieldMapping, Project.Models">
              <SourceFieldID>{1D747EFC-EBD6-43FB-BA0F-9A252FC05E43}</SourceFieldID>
              <TargetStandardValueFieldName>name</TargetStandardValueFieldName>
            </StandardValueFieldMapping>

            <StandardValueFieldMapping type="Project.StandardValueFieldMapping, Project.Models">
              <SourceFieldID>{77741F9A-523B-4CE8-886B-A6F4EB6C37DF}</SourceFieldID>
              <TargetStandardValueFieldName>description</TargetStandardValueFieldName>
            </StandardValueFieldMapping>
          </FieldMappings>
        </add>
      </providers>
    </standardValues>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>

Updates class file
   public class CategoryStandardValuesProvider : StandardValuesProvider, ISwitchingStandardValuesProvider
   {
       #region Private Properties
       private readonly Dictionary<ID, string> _fieldMapping;
       private readonly ID _commerceConnectProductClassificationFieldID;
       private readonly BaseItemManager _itemManager;
       private readonly BaseTemplateManager _templateManager;
       private readonly BaseFactory _factory;
       #endregion

       #region Public Properties
       public IDictionary<ID, string> FieldMappings
       {
           get { return _fieldMapping; }
       }
       #endregion

       #region Constructor
       public CategoryStandardValuesProvider(
           string commerceConnectProductClassificationFieldID,
           BaseItemManager itemManager,
           BaseTemplateManager templateManager,
           BaseFactory factory)
           : base(itemManager, templateManager, factory)
       {
           Assert.ArgumentNotNull(itemManager, nameof(itemManager));
           Assert.ArgumentNotNull(templateManager, nameof(templateManager));
           Assert.ArgumentNotNull(factory, nameof(factory));
           Assert.IsNotNullOrEmpty(commerceConnectProductClassificationFieldID, nameof(commerceConnectProductClassificationFieldID));

           _itemManager = itemManager;
           _templateManager = templateManager;
           _factory = factory;
           _fieldMapping = new Dictionary<ID, string>();

           if (!ID.TryParse(commerceConnectProductClassificationFieldID, out _commerceConnectProductClassificationFieldID))
           {
               throw new ArgumentException($"Invalid ID format: {commerceConnectProductClassificationFieldID}",
                   nameof(commerceConnectProductClassificationFieldID));
           }
       }
       #endregion

       #region Public Methods
       public void AddFieldMappings(StandardValueFieldMapping mapping)
       {
           Assert.ArgumentNotNull(mapping, nameof(mapping));
           Assert.IsNotNullOrEmpty(mapping.SourceFieldID, nameof(mapping.SourceFieldID));
           Assert.IsNotNullOrEmpty(mapping.TargetStandardValueFieldName, nameof(mapping.TargetStandardValueFieldName));

           _fieldMapping.Add(ID.Parse(mapping.SourceFieldID), mapping.TargetStandardValueFieldName);
       }
       #endregion

       #region Public Overrides
       public override string GetStandardValue(Field field)
       {
           Assert.ArgumentNotNull(field, nameof(field));
           Assert.ArgumentNotNull(field.Item, "field.Item");

           // If our field list contains this ID map it to the CC product
           if (_fieldMapping.ContainsKey(field.ID))
           {
               // Check the CC product and see if that item exists
               var ccItemField = field.Item.Fields[_commerceConnectProductClassificationFieldID];
               if (ccItemField != null)
               {
                   var ccItemFieldValue = ccItemField.Value;
                   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ccItemFieldValue))
                   {
                       var ccProduct = field.Item.Database.GetItem(ccItemFieldValue, field.Item.Language);
                       if (ccProduct != null)
                       {
                           // Get the mapped field value
                           var mappedField = ccProduct.Fields[_fieldMapping[field.ID]];
                           if (mappedField != null)
                           {
                               return mappedField.Value;
                           }
                       }
                   }
               }
           }

           // If we fall through return the base
           return base.GetStandardValue(field);
       }
       #endregion
   }


You are gettting this error since string type is not resolved through dependency injection. In order to add multiple providers for standard value, you will need to extend the StandardValuesProvider provider as below.
using Sitecore.Abstractions;
using Sitecore.Data;
using Sitecore.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

public class CategoryStandardValuesProvider : StandardValuesProvider
{
   public string CommerceConnectProductClassificationFieldID { get; set; }
   public CategoryStandardValuesProvider(string commerceConnectProductClassificationFieldID)
   : this(commerceConnectProductClassificationFieldID, ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<BaseItemManager>(), ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<BaseTemplateManager>(), ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<BaseFactory>())
   {

   }

   public CategoryStandardValuesProvider(string commerceConnectProductClassificationFieldID,BaseItemManager itemManager,BaseTemplateManager templateManager,BaseFactory factory) : base(itemManager, templateManager, factory)
   {
      Assert.ArgumentNotNull(itemManager, nameof(itemManager));
      Assert.ArgumentNotNull(templateManager, nameof(templateManager));
      Assert.ArgumentNotNull(factory, nameof(factory));
      Assert.IsNotNullOrEmpty(commerceConnectProductClassificationFieldID, nameof(commerceConnectProductClassificationFieldID));

     _itemManager = itemManager;
     _templateManager = templateManager;
     _factory = factory;
     _fieldMapping = new Dictionary<ID, string>();

     if (!ID.TryParse(commerceConnectProductClassificationFieldID, out _commerceConnectProductClassificationFieldID))
     {
           throw new ArgumentException($"Invalid ID format: {commerceConnectProductClassificationFieldID}",
                    nameof(commerceConnectProductClassificationFieldID));
     }
  }
}

You can remove the resolve=true from the configuration added above for CategoryStandardValuesProvider provider as its not required.
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <standardValues>
      <providers>
        <add name="CategoryStandardValuesProvider" type="Project.Common.Providers.CategoryStandardValuesProvider, Project.Common">
          <param name="commerceConnectProductClassificationFieldID">{C14B0AAA-0936-4B73-BD07-8B540C0B4B14}</param>
          <FieldMappings>
             ...
          </FieldMappings>
        </add>
      </providers>
    </standardValues>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>

Using above changes, the error you are getting should be resolved. You can read more here on the provider configuration.
Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you face any issues.

updated the class file in the question. and if i remove the resolve=true getting the error  no constructor found.

@Rameshkumar Also update the constructor function as above...

@Rameshkumar I have updated the answer above for the class. You can refer to the same and implement at your end. Let me know in case you get any issue.

i have used your code but same issue

@Rameshkumar Its working fine at my end..Hope you removed resolve=true for this class in the configuration and you are not registering this class in the service collection.

can you add the code for registering the class in service collection

@Rameshkumar We do not require to add this in service collection. Is it possible to connect over Sitecore Slack?

Your error indicates that Sitecore's dependency injection system is attempting to resolve a constructor parameter of type System.String, but it doesn't know how to supply a value for it. So in order to solve this issue please check all bellow steps may these steps help you.
Ensure Proper Constructor and DI Registration: Make sure that your wCategoryStandardValuesProvider constructor matches the expected parameters and that you're correctly injecting those parameters. For example:
public class wCategoryStandardValuesProvider
{
    private readonly string _commerceConnectProductClassificationFieldID;
    
    public wCategoryStandardValuesProvider(string commerceConnectProductClassificationFieldID)
    {
        _commerceConnectProductClassificationFieldID = commerceConnectProductClassificationFieldID;
    }

    // Other methods here
}


Using IConfiguration to Pass Parameters: Instead of directly passing String parameters via XML, consider using Sitecore's configuration system to resolve these values via dependency injection.
public static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<string>(sp => "{C14B0AAA-0936-4B73-BD07-8B540C0B4B14}");
    services.AddTransient<wCategoryStandardValuesProvider>();
}


Pass Parameters in Configuration File: Ensure your config file correctly defines the parameter and that Sitecore is aware of how to inject it:
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <standardValues>
      <patch:attribute name="defaultProvider" value="wCategoryStandardValuesProvider" />
      <providers>
        <add name="wCategoryStandardValuesProvider" type="Project.ww.Common.Providers.wCategoryStandardValuesProvider, Project.ww.Common" resolve="true">
          <param name="commerceConnectProductClassificationFieldID">{C14B0AAA-0936-4B73-BD07-8B540C0B4B14}</param>
        </add>
      </providers>
    </standardValues>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>


Hope this help!!
